# Одна или несколько таблиц для хранения контента

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Доброго времени суток. При разработке проекта, задался вопросом, как лучше с точки зрения правильности, структурировать БД (MySQL движок MyISAM), а именно, в одной или нескольких таблицах хранить контент?

Приведу два пример.

**Пример 1.**
[image]

Данный пример взят с CMF MODx. Его особенность в том, что весь контент храниться в одной таблице, кроме данных о пользователе, правах и т.д. Сущности (к примеру, статьи, новости, теги…) разделены за счёт поля "context".
Учитывая то, с какой интенсивностью добавляются новости, теги,… (сущностей может быть сколько угодно много), можно представить, как быстро будет разбухать единое хранилище контента (таблица "content"). Понимаю, что количество хранимых в таблице записей ограничено, лишь файловой системой, но всё же.

**Пример 2.**

[image]

Отличие от первого примера, лишь в том, что опущено поле "context", а сущности разделены "физически", т.е. по таблицам.

Существует условное правило, если поля таблиц равноценны (одинаковы), то объедение несколько таблиц в одну, приветствуется.

В пользу второго примера я бы отнёс возможный в будущем шардинг по конкретным сущностям.
К недостаткам: пришлось усложнить логику для реализации функционала отображения тематически похожего материала для отдельно взятой статьи.

Уважаемые Гуру, подскажите, какое из этих двух решений на ваш взгляд является предпочтительным?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лично я бы, людей, придумавших первых вариант долго бил бы палкой по рукам. У Вас есть 2 разные! сущности, данные о которых целесообразно хранить в разных таблицах. Как говорится, котлеты отдельно, мухи отдельно.

Comment: @masterMind Согласен. Видимо в CMS-ках исходя из безопасности, добавление/удаление таблиц в админке нецелесообразно, потому носителем сущности выступает запись (в моём примере, это запись в поле "context").

Comment: Это как посмотреть. В каких-то ситуациях удобнее рассматривать «новости» и «статьи» как разные сущности, в каких-то как одну. Я-бы не был столь категоричен. В конце концов кроме мух и котлет есть ещё Оккам с его бритвой.

Comment: Расскажите как вы сделаете полнотекстовый поиск по статьям и новостям, сортированный по релевантности. не привлекая сфинкс и прочие танцы с бубном (типа union или or и/или временной таблицы)... / Это все к тому, что надо подходить к задаче с умом, а не "тут так заведено".

Answer (score 2):

Первое конечно и лучше и удобнее. А шардинг нужно будет делать на объемах, когда в таблице будут дестки миллионов записей. И его лучше делать не по типу сущности, а по id (четные - в одну БД, нечетные в другую).

Чуть больше [про шардинг](http://highload.com.ua/index.php/2009/05/06/%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86/).

Answer (score 2):

Я выношу всё в отдельный таблицы:

```
news - id,parent
news_name - id,parent,name 
news_title - id,parent,title
news_content - id,parent,content
```

Comment: любите join'ы и мультивставки? так жить нельзя, тем более что оправдание для такого подхода придумать сложно.

Answer (score 1):

Есть такое понятие как [нормализация базы данных](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0). Оно является одним из основополагающих при проектировании любой БД. Про это надо как минимум знать и понимать зачем это сделано.

З.Ы. Да в некоторых случаях применяется **осознанная** денормализация БД, но для этого должны быть созданы определенные условия.

Comment: В теории реляционной модели данных я не силён, но на сколько я понимаю идею нормализации она тут не причём. Хотя знать про неё, работая с РСУБД, конечно-же нужно.